# IntelliJ can't handle different module versions in separate projects

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I've got 2 distinct projects (`A` and `B`) and both depend on module `X`, but different versions of it:

- Project `A` depends on a jar built from module `X-1.0`
- Project `B` depends on module `X-2.0`, and that module is part of the project.

My problem is that IntelliJ simply can't handle having projects `A` and `B` open at the same time because of the dependency of different versions of the same module and I get lots of compilation errors with classes not found. It goes crazy and closing one of the projects doesn't solve the problem if I mistakenly open both of them at the same time. Things break so bad that the project can only be built and execute again after invalidating caches and restarting.

Is there any known alternative or workaround to be able to work on projects `A` and `B` at the same time?

Comment: Please [file a bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA) with the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) attached.

Comment: Working on multiple versions of projects with different module version dependencies, while also working on that project is something I do everyday, mostly without issues. I use maven to manage dependencies and I manually accept Pom dependency changes.

Comment: this seems quite unusual... but are you using some dependency management tool. I will recommend using maven project set up

Comment: I'm using maven.

Comment: ok in that case, im using latest version of intellij with maven multimodule project with complex dependency tree n its able to resolve. cause dependencies and build life cycle is managed by maven which does it in fantastic way. n it happens at jar level. at the max intellij may show too source locations but it should not cause build failure.

Comment: The problem is related to having two different project windows open, not a single project with lots of dependencies.

Comment: Also try this, after building projects with "mvn clean install -U" try n using button on intellij's maven panel there is button for reimport maven project. click it, this sometimes takes care of caching issue

Comment: Is the project X also maven project? Does it have the versions set correctly in the pom? (1.0 for X-1.0, 2.0 for X-2.0...)?

Comment: Yes, and everything works individually. Things only go crazy if I open project A and B at the same time (each on its own window). I'll try to replicate this in an example and submit a bug report to jetbrains when I get the time.